# Is there any way to load Vue js Library into Pug template without adding CDN

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, pug

I have this question in my mind for a long time. Let's say I installed Vue JS or any other library through npm. Then how can I load that particular library into the pug template?. Isn't it possible ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can include a virtual path to the route and then we can access the javascript file as follows.

**In Router JS**

```
router.use('/javascript', express.static(path.join(path.dirname(require.main.filename), 'public')));
```

**In Pug Template**

```
script(src='/simple-api/javascript/test.js')
```

Consider "simple-api" is the public URL.